# Flag notification icon doesn't always appear reliably

Tags: bug, flags

From time to time on the two sites I moderate (Photography and Pets), I've noticed that the pending moderation flag icon doesn't always appear with a first hit or refresh of a site page, but if I immediately refresh, any pending flags will then appear. There are pending flags waiting at that time since I've monitored flags where I've applied a post notice, have come back and it's been gone, click through to the history and see that it's still there and now showing.

This is *not* related to the new bar, the condition existed prior to the introduction of the new bar.

Comment: I've noticed this too. It's been going on for months.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, the difference here isn't that it's inaccurate. It's that it just sometimes doesn't show at all.

Comment: @jmort Still caching, though - right? Same root issue.

Comment: @UndotheSnowman - No, it's not caching if it appears, disappears, and then reappears within seconds. If it is caching, it's crap caching to say the least.

Comment: Retracted the close vote - not being a mod makes it a little harder to really get these things. It could still be client-side caching, though - I can make a similar thing happen even on post edits where Chrome won't show an edit until a force-refresh.

Comment: @UndotheSnowman - Still, just because caching is involved in both cases doesn't make it a dup. It would suck if John didn't report this, waited for the devs to fix the issue from May, only for John to still face the issue because he thought the devs would fix *all* caching issues but didn't. :D

Comment: @UndotheSnowman - Could be, I'm a Chrome user and I've seen this on both Mac and Windows. I wouldn't rule out the client in any event.

Comment: I think this is updated via web sockets... maybe your web socket connection isn't stable?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Happens at home, happens at work, and happens when I'm travelling. So, maybe, but other features such as rep updates and message notifications are reliable.

Comment: I see. So maybe bug only in the mod flags queue indeed... hope a dev will come over and fix or explain soon.